# Dynamically embed dlls in Resources at compile time in VS2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Is it possible to compile/build a plugin library that contains embed dlls into its Resources dynamically?

For example, I have the following dlls (old c or c++ dll that will need dllImport):

```
MyProject
  + Dlls
    + Name1
        a.dll
        b.dll
    + Name2
        a.dll (same name, but compiled differently)
        c.dll
        d.dll
    + Name-n
```

And I want to generates different wrapped dlls with the above dlls embedded to it.

```
Hello.Name1.dll (this contains a.dll and b.dll)
Hello.Name2.dll (this contains a.dll, c.dll and d.dll)
```

Edit:

I know I could add them in Resources and then extract them dynamically, that is exactly what I had before, but I do not want to bundle everything into a giant dll.

My goal here is to split them up, and use `Reflection` later to determine whether a `Name1` or `Name2` dll exists programatically, then load and extract the dlls/content.

Comment: You can add them as resources (byte arrays aka files in the editor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx) then extract them at runtime and drop them somewhere safe (File.WriteAllBytes(Properties.Resources.MuhDllLol)).

Comment: Yes, but that would be adding ALL of them into ONE (or all) of the compiled dll. That's what I have before and realized I want to split them up so that in other project, I only need to include a smaller dll.